# Does the Void's power cancel out the Spiff's?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

In cosmic encounter, one player is the Void (destroys ships instead of sending them to the warp), and another player is the Spiff (attacking player still gets a colony if they lose by 10 or more). If the Spiff attack the Void and lose when they have 5+ ships, do they still get a colony, or is the ship that would become the colony destroyed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ship is destroyed. Both abilities are trying to interact with ships that would be going to the void. The [FAQ for the Fantasy Flight](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Cosmic%20Encounter/faq/cosmicfaq_v1.0.pdf) version (the most recent to date),  indicates that **Void** trumps all other abilities.

> **Q: Is there an official ruling on Zombie vs Void?**
>
> A: Void trumps Zombie. Zombie's power kicks in when it should go to the warp, however the intent for Void is that it never sends its opponents to the warp at all.

This ruling is not at all obvious when you consider the text on the various cards, and their updated errata. (from the [CE Cosmodex](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5174376#5174376))

> **Spiff** - Receives Colony as Loser (G) You have the power to Crash Land. As the offense, if both players revealed attack cards and {your total was 10 or more less than the defense's} you lost the encounter by 10 or more, you may use this power to land one of your ships that would otherwise be lost to the warp on the winning planet. {The ship coexists with the ships already there. This power does not allow you to coexist in places or with aliens that state otherwise.}
>
> **Void** - Eradicates Opponents' Ships (R) You have the power to Eradicate. As a main player, when you win an encounter, use this power to remove the losing side's ships from the game rather than sending them to the warp. This occurs before any other game effects that affect ships headed to the warp. A player cannot be reduced to fewer ships than the number of foreign colonies needed to win the game. Any eradicated ships that would reduce a player below this number are sent to the warp as usual.

Comment: The key text here being in the Void description: **"This occurs before any other game effects that affect ships headed to the warp"**